# Java - listFiles() returns nullpointerexception

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Well I'm running a Runnable JAR File exported from eclipse and I'm getting a NullPointerException(on a Linux VPS). In my Windows PC, it works perfectly file. This is my code:

```
public Main() throws Throwable {
    Policy.setPolicy(new PluginPolicy());
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

    File directory = new File("src/Plugins/Rogue/");

    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if(fList.length > 0) { 
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                String path = file.getParent().substring(4).replace("\\", ".");
                String pluginName = file.getName().split("\\.")[0];

                File unauthorizedJarFile = new File(pluginName + ".jar");
                ClassLoader unauthorizedLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { unauthorizedJarFile.toURI().toURL() });
                Plugin unauthorizedPlugin = (Plugin) unauthorizedLoader.loadClass(path + "." + pluginName).newInstance();
                unauthorizedPlugin.run();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this in my Linux VPS:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Test.Main.<init>(Main.java:23)
        at Test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

and on my Eclipse IDE on Windows:

```
Rogue.java
swaggy!
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Where is this folder? It looks a lot like you're trying to read a resource on the classpath as a file...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I do not understand. The folder is the src folder

Comment: [File#listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) might return `null` and you don't verify that. Is your question why it returns `null`?

Comment: Well, first - what is the CWD of the program in both cases. Is the `src` folder there? Further, file paths don't use `\\` on Unix systems - this code will never de cross platform.

Comment: @RC. Yes and how can I fix it?

Comment: As said by Boris, don't use "\\" on unix systems as path separator (hint: use the constant defined in `File`)

Comment: @RC. I don't think that's the right route either. `File.equals` works perfectly and will take account of the separator. The OP just needs to not compare the file paths as strings.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In my Windows PC: C:\Users\MyName\workspace\Testing and on Linux VPS: /FolderName. The src folder is not in my Linux VPS. If I do put the src folder on my VPS then it will print out file name but another exception pops out `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName:Plugins/Rogue.Rogue`

Comment: @BoristheSpider yup, but he will have to take caution when doing his split etc

Comment: @ct12 so when you add the folder to the right place then the program finds the folder. No surprise there. If you want an answer to your other question you should either delete this question and ask another or edit this question to ask the right question. You main issue is a file separator one - you have hardcoded the Windows path separator everywhere.

Comment: 1- If the abstract pathname does not exist the calling `listFiles` will return `null`; 2- It is unlikely that `src` will exist once the program is actually build; 3- You should not be referencing the `src` directory within your code, for the previous reason; 3- If you've jar'd your application, the plugins directory will be embedded within the jar, meaning that it is not accessible via the `java.io.File` API...

Comment: @MadProgrammer that was my first thought - but the OP seems to be copying the src folder around. In any case; this question is now a little too broad.

Comment: @MadProgrammer #3, is there any other way without using `java.io.File` API? Apache Commons?

Comment: @ct12 yes. Use the classloader. But this is straying wildly from the original question asked.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Is there anyway I can contact you? Email? Skype?

Comment: Usually what I do is have a list of content stored in a file, then I can use `Class#getResource` to load the list and use that to determine what I need to copy, again using `Class#getResourceAsStream`. With plugins, I normally store them in a relative location from the program (ie `./plugins`), I list the contents (`*.jar`), use the `JarFile` to inspect them for a "plugin entry", which is a special file placed in a predetermined location within the Jar, which describes the plugin...